# Row_Number() and T-SQL View

Tags: t-sql

I am trying to implement paging for a View in T-SQL :

```
with TH_VW_UserFollowing  as
(
Select  FollowerID, 
        FollowingID, 
        FollowingFullName, 
        FollowingImage, 
        FollowingUserName,
        dbo.GetUserFollowers(FollowingID) AS Followers,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by dbo.GetUserFollowers(FollowingID) DESC ) AS 'RowNumber'   
from dbo.TH_VW_UserFollowing 
where FollowerID = @UserID 
)
Select  FollowerID, 
        FollowingID, 
        FollowingFullName, 
        FollowingImage, 
        FollowingUserName, Followers
from dbo.TH_VW_UserFollowing
Where RowNumber BETWEEN @startIdx AND @endIdx
```

For a reason I am getting these errors :

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure GetUserUsersFollowing, Line 36
>   Invalid column name 'RowNumber'. Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure
>   GetUserUsersFollowing, Line 36 Invalid column name 'RowNumber'. Msg
>   207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure GetUserUsersFollowing, Line 34
>   Invalid column name 'Followers'.

I've used the same code for a table, but I don't know what is happening here. something is missing...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're selecting from the **table** and not the CTE you defined above.  You should be doing in your final SELECT, "FROM TH_VW_UserFollowing".  I'd also suggest giving your CTE a different name from your table.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you name the cte the same as the view name?